# Проблема с собственной функцией

Tags: php, массивы, функции

У меня есть функция, которая фиксит ошибки `Undefined index` и `Undefined offset`:

```
function exst(&$var = null) {
 return ((!isset($var) || !$var) ? null : $var);
}
```

С переменными `exst($perem)` работает всё отлично, а вот с массивом какая-то беда, зачем-то создаётся ещё один элемент массива.

Что я сделал не так? Почему создаётся ещё один элемент массива?

```
$arr = array('a', 'b');

if(exst($arr[3])) {

}

print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы передаете переменную по ссылке, что еще вы ожидаете? В тот момент, когда вы ее пытаетесь передать, и создается элемент массива.

> У меня есть функция, которая фиксит ошибки Undefined index и Undefined offset:

Она ничего не фиксит. Это не только кхм странное решение, но и работающее в тот момент, **когда данные в него уже передали**, когда уже то, чего вы пытаетесь избежать уже свершилось.

Не изобретайте костыли и используйте обычный `isset($container[$index])`. Если нужна краткость при присвоении - используйте обертки или тернарный оператор.

Comment: так уж и быть. Спасибо.